Does a lattice system have an intrinsic coordinate system based on which orbitals are defined?
When one plots probability density associated to say d-orbitals of an atom, its lobes are supposed to be pointed in XY plane for $\textit{$d_{xy}$}$ and so on. But isn't this dependent on the coordinate system one defines? Is it that for a free atom floating in space, the coordinates should hold a relative meaning only?
Also, when we consider atoms in a perfect lattice, do the directional orbitals like $\textit{$d_{z^2}$}$ have a fixed orientation relative to the lattice?

For an isolated H atom: generally a state in the p orbital is a linear combination of $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$.  You are of course free to rotate the Cartesian axes, and represent the same state in another basis.  In that regard, the choice of coordinates is arbitrarily imposed by human, and not inherent to the actual physics.
But the p state carries angular momentum one and behaves like a vector.  It is not rotationally invariant.  So a p state inherently specifies a direction in space, and that intrinsic direction is not affected by any change of the human-defined coordinates.
In a crystalline solid you lose full rotational invariance.  Anything that has an inherent directionality, i.e. any vector quantity (and indeed any higher rank tensor) will align with the lattice directions.  You are still free to put the human-defined coordinates in any orientation, but not aligning with the lattice is just asking for unnecessary trouble.

Thanks, T. Can you point out some references where I can look for information on how to figure out this directionality in any given crystalline system?
I am guessing that suppose you have a crystal whose atom aligns itself so that the n-th p orbital makes a bond. Now, all its (n-1)th orbitals would have a direction according to the same coordinate system. Is it so?

You're right, the orientation of the orbitals with respect to the coordinate axes obviously depends on the choice of the axes. It is just a matter of labeling points in space, this does not change the orbitals themselves.
In the context of solid materials, orbitals are no longer a very good description of electrons because they are now in a periodic potential rather than in that of a single nucleus. The electronic structure is described by bands rather than orbitals.

Thanks Perttu. I was thinking that if you plot the probability density corresponding to the orbital itself, what would you see? Like, if we take an H atom with its electron excited to n=2, shouldn't the charge density look like an overlap of 2s, 2p_x, 2p_y, and 2p_z orbitals? Won't there be some directionality in the plotted probability density (here charge density)?
Also, in the solids, atoms have fairly localized electrons belonging to the inner shell which retain their atomic orbital character (flat band at highly negative energies compared to fermi level). Will they have a directionality?
